# Images based on Array Values

Tags: android, arrays, image, dice

I have a dice game and I am trying to change the image of the Die that is selected after the dice are rolled to a "Dead Die" image.  I have tried everything I can think of and I always end up finding the Value "0" in the Index or something else but never the correct Die.

When the dice is selected it sets it's value to a Negative Number.  Example I select 6 it changes the value to -6 and changes the die to the -6 die image

How can I get it to display AND KEEP the "DEAD" image I want.

Here is the area where it gets the Images

```
            //Get the Dice Images
           public Integer getImage(int index) {
               if (diceValues[index] == 0) {
                       return letterImages.get(index);

               } else {
                       return diceImages.get((diceValues[index]));
               }
           }
```

I have tried changing

```
return letterImages.get(index);
```

to every possible combination of everything and when I do get it to change the image it always ends up at "0" or the the current number of dice selected or the some other number that I'm just not sure how it came up with.

Here is the entire DieManager class

```
package com.mygames.dice;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.util.Log;

public class DieManager {

        // Will return the Indexes of the dice when this is used
        public static final int INDEX_FLAG = 1;
        // Will return the values of the dice when this is used
        public static final int VALUE_FLAG = 2;
        // Will return the absolute values of the dice when this is used
        public static final int ABS_VALUE_FLAG = 3;

        // The array that holds the dice
        private int[] diceValues = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        private HashMap<Integer, Integer> diceImages = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        private HashMap<Integer, Integer> deadImages = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        private HashMap<Integer, Integer> letterImages = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        // Sets @newValue to dieValues[@index]
        public void setValue(int index, int newValue) {
                Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Index = " + index + " Value = " + newValue);
                diceValues[index] = newValue;
        }

        public DieManager() {
                super();
                initializeMaps();
        }

        private void initializeMaps() {

                diceImages.put(-6, R.drawable.die6_select);
                diceImages.put(-5, R.drawable.die5_select);
                diceImages.put(-4, R.drawable.die4_select);
                diceImages.put(-3, R.drawable.die3_select);
                diceImages.put(-2, R.drawable.die2_select);
                diceImages.put(-1, R.drawable.die1_select);

                diceImages.put(1, R.drawable.die1_roll);
                diceImages.put(2, R.drawable.die2_roll);
                diceImages.put(3, R.drawable.die3_roll);
                diceImages.put(4, R.drawable.die4_roll);
                diceImages.put(5, R.drawable.die5_roll);
                diceImages.put(6, R.drawable.die6_roll);


                deadImages.put(-1, R.drawable.die1_dead);
                deadImages.put(-2, R.drawable.die2_dead);
                deadImages.put(-3, R.drawable.die3_dead);
                deadImages.put(-4, R.drawable.die4_dead);
                deadImages.put(-5, R.drawable.die5_dead);
                deadImages.put(-6, R.drawable.die6_dead);

                letterImages.put(0, R.drawable.die_no);
                letterImages.put(1, R.drawable.die_no);
                letterImages.put(2, R.drawable.die_no);
                letterImages.put(3, R.drawable.die_no);
                letterImages.put(4, R.drawable.die_no);
                letterImages.put(5, R.drawable.die_no);

        }

        public void rollDice() {

                boolean isNewRound = (numOnTable() == 0);
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

                        // If its a new round then the dice value can be changed from 0.
                        // Else it can't
                        if (isNewRound || diceValues[j] != 0)
                                diceValues[j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
                }
        }

        // Returns the value or absolute value
        public int getValue(int index, int flag) {
                if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG)
                        return Math.abs(diceValues[index]);

                return diceValues[index];
        }

        // If a dice value is 0 then its a letter
        public int numOnTable() {
                int count = 6;
                for (int i : diceValues) {
                        if (i == 0)
                                count--;
                }
                return count;
        }

        // Picking up makes the dice value 0
        public void pickUp(int[] highlighted) {

                for (int i = 0; i < highlighted.length; i++)
                        diceValues[highlighted[i]] = 0;

        }

        // A negative value means a die is highlighted
        public void toggleHighlight(int index) {
                diceValues[index] *= -1;
        }

        public void clearTable() {
                diceValues[0] = 0;
                diceValues[1] = 0;
                diceValues[2] = 0;
                diceValues[3] = 0;
                diceValues[4] = 0;
                diceValues[5] = 0;

        }

        // Return the dice that aren't 0
        public int[] diceOnTable(int flag) {
                if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG) {
                        int[] array = new int[diceValues.length];

                        for (int i = 0; i < diceValues.length; i++)
                                array[i] = Math.abs(diceValues[i]);

                        return array;
                }

                return diceValues;
        }

        //Returns dice that are negative
        public int[] getHighlighted(int flag) {
                int[] dirtyArray = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                int count = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                        if (diceValues[j] < 0) {

                                if (flag == INDEX_FLAG)
                                        dirtyArray[count++] = j;

                                if (flag == VALUE_FLAG)
                                        dirtyArray[count++] = diceValues[j];

                                if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG)
                                        dirtyArray[count++] = Math.abs(diceValues[j]);
                        }
                }

                int[] cleanArray = new int[count];

                //Returns an array of length 0
                if (count == 0)
                        return cleanArray;

                System.arraycopy(dirtyArray, 0, cleanArray, 0, count);
                return cleanArray;

        }

        // Finds in dieValues same @value and excludes @index
        public int[] findPairs(int index, int flag) {

                int[] dirtyArray = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

                int count = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

                        if (j != index
                                        && Math.abs(diceValues[j]) == Math.abs(diceValues[index])) {

                                if (flag == INDEX_FLAG)
                                        dirtyArray[count++] = j;

                                if (flag == VALUE_FLAG)
                                        dirtyArray[count++] = diceValues[j];

                                if (flag == ABS_VALUE_FLAG)
                                        dirtyArray[count++] = Math.abs(diceValues[j]);
                        }

                }

                int[] cleanArray = new int[count];

                if (count == 0)
                        return cleanArray;

                System.arraycopy(dirtyArray, 0, cleanArray, 0, count);
                return cleanArray;
        }

            //Get the Dice Images
           public Integer getImage(int index) {
               if (diceValues[index] == 0) {
                       return letterImages.get(index);

               } else {
                       return diceImages.get((diceValues[index]));
               }
           }

            //Get the Number of dice remaining that are not 0
            public int numDiceRemain() {
                int counter = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < diceValues.length; j++) { 
                        if (diceValues[j] > 0)
                            counter++;
                }
                return counter;
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dice value can never be zero on a roll because of the following line in your rollDice() method:

```
diceValues[j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
```

And this seems logical to me.  Why would the value on a die ever be zero?

Comment: Your correct on Roll, but after the dice is selected "on "pickup"" and you roll again, it's value becomes "0" So it gets marked as a Dead Die after the score.